# prepend email addresses with string in mongodb collection using mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

My collection has a column named email which contains email address. Now I need to update all these email addresses, appending _01 at the end of the email (before @). Basically if the email is `ipman@gmail.com`, it should be converted to `ipman_01@gmail.com`. I know we can use `updateMany` to update multiple documents using mongoose, but to achieve what I need, I believe I need to use some kind of regex too?

Comment: What is your mongoDB version ?

Comment: @srinivasy it's 4.0.7

Comment: How big is your dataset ?

Comment: the collection size is only about 1.6k, But I want to apply these to selected dataset in the collection (only 63 records) which I will use find in Array

Comment: : Ok for just 63 records and with 4.0 maybe you can just read, manipulate data and write it back that would be easy to do, use bulkwrite() to write all records back in one DB call. let me know if you need any help with that..

Comment: @srinivasy yeah I was thinking of doing just like you mentioned but I've never used bulkwrite before, so maybe I'd just do update in promise. Actually I asked in SO just to see if there's an easier way/built in function in mongoose to do this

Comment: I can give you a query using bulkwrite then

Comment: Is it working or still having any issues ? If it is can you please accept it :-)

Comment: sorry I was bogged down with another task. I'll test your code today and inform you accordingly k. thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this :

```
let emails = ['ipman@gmail.com', 'ipman2@gmail.com']

let bulkArr = [];
for (const i of emails) {
    let newEmail = i.split("@");
    newEmail = newEmail[0] + '_01' + '@' + newEmail[1]
    bulkArr.push({
        updateOne: {
            "filter": { email : i },
            "update": { '$set': { email : newEmail } }
        }
    })
}

let updateResult = await MongooseModel.bulkWrite( bulkArr, { ordered : false }) 
/** Passing { ordered : false } to make sure update op doesn't fail if updating one document in the middle fails, Also bulkWrite returns write result check documentation for more info */
console.log('matchedCount ::', updateResult.matchedCount, 'modifiedCount ::', updateResult.modifiedCount)
```

**Ref :** [.bulkWrite()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/index.html)