# MongoDB UpdateMany with multiple filters

Tags: mongodb, insert-update

Normally `updateMany()` in mongoDB works like this:

```
db.coll.updateMany(
<filter>, <update data>, {...other options})
```

What if I want to update X no of documents with X no of unique _id in one query? Is there any work around except for looping?

Comment: So if you've X num of unique `_id`s to be updated with different type of data for each one of those then try this bulkWrite which can update up-to 100K docs in a request :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59883845/prepend-email-addresses-with-string-in-mongodb-collection-using-mongoose/59890016#59890016 , let me know if it works or not :-)